# Unix shell script to remove new lines preceded with specific characters

Tags: shell, unix, sed, newline, lf

First, thanks in advance for your helps.

I need to replace new lines (\n) by a space in an unix files when they are not preceded with ';'.

For example, if you have in an unix file something like :

```
TestFields;TestFields2
;TestFields3;TestFields4
```

The output should be :

```
TestFields;TestFields2 ;TestFields3;TestFields4
```

So I am using a sed command like that :

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/[^;]\n/ /g'
```

The problem is that this command will replace also the character which is before \n so my outpu is like :

```
TestFields;TestFields ;TestFields3;TestFields4
```

I loose the '2' in the 'TestFields2' ..
Someone have an idea on how to keep my character but replace the \n ?

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\([^;]\)\n/\1 /g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

capture the matched char and use in replacement

```
$ sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/([^;])\n/\1 /g' file
TestFields;TestFields2 ;TestFields3;TestFields4
```

g suffix is probably not needed.

Comment: No need to use ERE when you can make this portable.

Comment: Thanks ! it's working, ( will put your answer when it will be enable)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/;\n/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

An alternative to slurping the whole file into memory and reads as the question was read i.e. if the character preceeding the newline is a `;` do nothing otherwise replace the newline by a space.